# Editing GML data in QGIS and also in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, editing, gml

I have a GML file with graphical and non-graphical layers, it opens in QGIS 2.11.14 but it doesn't allow anything but read permission. I can't edit new attributes or rewrite it... it seems like the GML is locked.

Why does it happen?

it also happens in ArcGIS...

Answer (score 2):

Gml or xml in general are formats that are not meant for editing in this way. They are used as a highly adaptable  (usually transport) format. An that is the problem for programs like Qgis or Arcgis. Reading is (often) possible as the file itself delivers the rules to be understood. But the writing can only be done to the standard gml as the programs would otherwise need to implement hundreds of different types of gml/xml.

The first question would be if it is a gml to the OGC standard? And not only the file extension. When this is the case you can export the gml to any editable format like FileGeodatabase or SpatialLite/Geopackage. Then edit it and export it back to gml.

But i doubt it when you say you have graphical and non-graphical layers. In this case you need to rewrite the file with all the definitions it got. Either by programming the parser yourself or by getting the conversion tool that is used for this special type of gml.

Understand a gml not as a file type but as a standard that can be nearly anything. It just uses the .gml extension to give a general idea to the programs that need to show them how they should handle it. Can you find out what type of gml you have? You can open it in any text editor and can have a look what namespaces it uses.