# Selecting certain text from attribute values in QGIS using field calculator

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, select-by-attribute, gml

I am using QGIS 3.16 (Field Calculator). I have a number of values in the attributes of my GML file that read:

- `'Nonconiferous Trees'` or
- `'Nonconiferous Trees (Scattered)'` or
- `'Nonconiferous Trees, Scrub'` or
- `'Nonconiferous Trees, Coniferous Trees'`.

I want to create a new attribute column called `Type` and select all those values containing the text `'Nonconiferous Trees'` and create a new value in the `Type` column called `'Mixed Woodland'`.
I am running

```
CASE
WHEN "descriptiveTerm" ILIKE '%Nonconiferous Trees%' THEN 'Mixed Woodland Fill'
END
```

But all it picks up is `'Nonconiferous Trees'` or `'Nonconiferous Trees (Scattered)'`. Its like it doesn't like the comma?

Comment: From you comments, it becomes clear that the problem is probably the GML format you use: these are not meant to be edited (in QGIS, at least). You should stick to Geopackage (preferably) or Shapefiles if you want to edit data. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226822/editing-gml-data-in-qgis-and-also-in-arcgis - with Geopacke, even you initial expression seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Use `regexp_match()` to find the features that contain the string 'Nonconiferous Trees', see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.htmlregexp-matches):

```
case
when regexp_match( descriptiveTerm, 'Nonconiferous Trees')
then 'Mixed Woodland Fill'
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I run this on my GML data it only picks up those values that have just Nonconiferious Trees or Nonconiferious Trees (Scattered). It ignores those like Nonconiferous, Scrub or Nonconiferous, Coniferous. ???

Comment: Can you provide sample data for testing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `LIKE` function, you can use it in the following way:

```
case
when  "FieldName" like ('Nonconiferous Trees%') then 'Mixed Woodland'
end
```

This means selecting all texts starting with `Nonconiferous Trees` and including additional texts afterward.

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I run this on my GML data it only picks up those values that have just Nonconiferious Trees or Nonconiferious Trees (Scattered). It ignores those like Nonconiferous, Scrub or Nonconiferous, Coniferous. ???

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyones help. The issue was an array thing and the array_match command worked in the end:

```
WHEN 
    ( array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Nonconiferous Trees') OR 
      array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Nonconiferous Trees (Scattered)') ) 
    AND 
    ( array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Coniferous Trees') OR 
      array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Coniferous Trees (Scattered)') )
THEN 
    'Mixed Woodland Fill'
```

Comment: Could you add the expression you used to your answer? It will help others having similar  issue in the future.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Expression used was;
WHEN ( array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Nonconiferous Trees') OR array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Nonconiferous Trees (Scattered)') )
  AND ( array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Coniferous Trees') OR array_contains(descriptiveTerm, 'Coniferous Trees (Scattered)') )
  THEN 'Mixed Woodland Fill'